# RMarkdown render from command line and clear .tex intermediate output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm using `rmarkdown::render` outside RStudio to knit a `.pdf` document. This is working fine but it leaves behind an intermediate `.tex` file that I don't want. I'm already using the `clear = TRUE` option for `rmarkdown::render`. I don't know what RStudio does but it does clear the `.tex` file when I knit the document from the IDE.

Comment: You can add `keep_tex: no` below `pdf_document:` in YAML header

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Also tried `keep_tex: false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`keep_tex: false` is indeed the way to go. You did not provide enough information for us to diagnose the problem.

```
library(rmarkdown)
temp_dir <- tempdir()

rmd <- '---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---'
cat(rmd, file = file.path(temp_dir, "keep_tex_true.rmd"))
render(file.path(temp_dir, "keep_tex_true.rmd"))
list.files(temp_dir)
# [1] "keep_tex_true.pdf" "keep_tex_true.rmd" "keep_tex_true.tex"

rmd <- '---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: false
---'
cat(rmd, file = file.path(temp_dir, "keep_tex_false.rmd"))
render(file.path(temp_dir, "keep_tex_false.rmd"))
list.files(temp_dir)
# [1] "keep_tex_false.pdf" "keep_tex_false.rmd" "keep_tex_true.pdf" 
# [4] "keep_tex_true.rmd"  "keep_tex_true.tex"
```

Comment: Weird, this works if I'm using Windows cmd but not if I'm using Git Bash (using the exact same code). Probably something to do with file path slashes because in Git Bash it works fine if the `.Rmd` file is in my working directory.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with `keep_tex: false` not working as expected. I'm using the RScript command line to rendering a PDF, with the command line containing `clean = true` arg and the Rmd file YAML header containing the `keep_tex: false` option. However it's still not clearing that file, nor a text log from the Xelatex engine that I'm using; could this be a cross-compatibility issue with Xelatex?